# Funcion belongToMany in other funcion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i have a my function

```
public function index(){
    $comments = ListsComments::orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )->where('is_admin_reply', 0)->get();
    return view( "admin.lists.comments.index", compact( 'comments' ) );
}
```

That give me all the comments but i only want the comments of lists this is my models of ListsComments

```
public function list(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Lists', 'list_has_comments' , 'comment_id', 'list_id');
}
```

In blade i am call him $comment->list but how that give me all the comments and some comments not are of list well that give me error, i understant i need call the list for make the call to the function list where is especified the table list_gas_comments but i dont kwno how make in the funcion index, regads.

Comment: do you want to get comments for a specific list in index action?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `with()`

```
public function index(){
$comments = ListsComments::with(['list'=> function($q){
   $q->first();
}])->orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )->where('is_admin_reply', 0)->get();
return view( "admin.lists.comments.index", compact( 'comments' ) );
}
```

you can also achieve this like. `$comment->list->first()`;

I am not about the second method but you can give it a try.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but that not work, at the end i use join for fuse the tables and can access to the user and list xD

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct('list');
}

public function __construct($relatedTable = ''){
    $this->relatedTable = $relatedTable;
}

public function adminComments(){
    $related = $this->relatedTable;
    $relationshipTable = $related . '_has_comments as relation';
    $relatedPlural = $related . 's as related';

    return DB::table('comments')
        ->join($relationshipTable, 'comments.id', '=', 'relation.comment_id')
        ->join($relatedPlural, 'relation.list_id', '=', 'related.id')
        ->join('users', 'relation.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('*');
}

public function index(){
    $listComment = new ListsComments();
    $comments = $listComment->adminComments()->paginate(10);
    return view( "admin.lists.comments.index", compact( 'comments') );
}
```